# Delegate method in second ViewController not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I want to pass data from one of my controller to another. For that purpose i implement delegate in second view controller (it called when use tap "plus" button on first view controller):

Declaration of delegate:

```
@protocol AddTaskDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addTask:(NSString*)task byDate:(NSDate*)date;

@end
```

Implementation of delegate:

```
- (IBAction)addTask:(id)sender {

    if ([self.addTextField.text length] >0){

        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

        [self.delegateObj addTask:self.addTextField.text byDate:now];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }   else {

        NSLog(@"You should type something");
    }

}
```

In `viewController1`:

```
addController.delegateObj = self;
...
```

Then:

```
   -(void)addTask:(NSString *)task byDate:(NSDate *)date  {

    myDateToFill  = date;
    myStringToFill = task;
    NSLog(@"myStringToFill is - %@", task);
    NSLog(@"method called");

}
```

However, `addTask` method not called (it suppose to return values calculated in second view controller). What did i miss?

UPDATE:

I update my `addTask` method for following and figure out my delegate object is nil:

```
- (IBAction)addTask:(id)sender {

    if ([self.addTextField.text length] >0){

        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"Prepare for repair");

        if (self.delegateObj == nil){
            NSLog(@"ALARM");
        }

        [self.delegateObj customMethod];
        [self.delegateObj taskAdded:self addTask:self.addTextField.text byDate:now];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }   else {

        NSLog(@"You should type something");
    }



}
```

Now in console i can see "Alarm" output, which tell me that self.delegateObj is nil for some reason.

Updated. Solved after that (and removing reference to AddTask controller from implementation):

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    // Если нету navigation Controller'a

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"add"]){

        UINavigationController *navController = [segue destinationViewController];
        AddViewController   *addController = (AddViewController*)([navController viewControllers][0]);
        addController.delegate = self;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have u conformed the delegate in the `protocol` in `ViewController1.h`?

Comment: Yes i did. Maybe i forgot to pass reference to ViewControllerB in delegate method?

Comment: Where do you set the reference to addController in viewController1

Comment: @zcui93 in implementation: AddViewController *addController;, then in viewDidLoad: addController.delegateObj = self;

Comment: Can you include the code in AddController where you set the delegate to the instance of viewController1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented the following in the `ViewController1.h`?

```
@interface ViewController1<AddTaskDelegate>
// ...
@end
```

and

in the AddTaskDelegate.h, the following line is missing

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddTaskDelegate> delegate;
```

in the AddTaskDelegate.m, add the following

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Additionally, I highly recommend you take a look at the following thread espcially @Tibidabo's answer: [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c?rq=1)